# ERROR 1172 (42000): Result consisted of more than one row on mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am getting ERROR 1172 (42000): Result consisted of more than one row on my stored procedure when I use CALL submitOrder( 10, 100, 1, @OrderId);

What went wrong in my code? The goal is to use the procedure to insert a new row into the orders table and a new row on the order details into order_items table.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE submitOrder(
IN customerId INT, 
IN productId INT, 
IN qty INT, 
OUT orderId INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE orderId, storeId, staffId, qty, customerId, productId INT; 
DECLARE listPrice DECIMAL(10,2); 
DECLARE discount DECIMAL(4,2);

SELECT MAX(order_id)+1 FROM orders INTO @orderId;

SELECT s.store_id
FROM stocks AS s
INNER JOIN products AS p USING (product_id)
WHERE p.product_id = s.product_id
ORDER BY s.quantity DESC
LIMIT 1
INTO @storeId;

SELECT staffs.staff_id 
FROM staffs
INNER JOIN stores
WHERE staffs.store_id = stores.store_id
LIMIT 1
INTO @staffID; 

SET @qty = 1;

SELECT products.product_id
FROM products
WHERE products.product_id = productId;

SELECT products.list_price
FROM products
INTO @listPrice;

INSERT INTO orders VALUES (
@orderId, @customerId, 1, CURDATE(), ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 day), NULL, @storeId, @staffId);

INSERT INTO order_items
VALUES (@orderId, 1, @productId, @qty, @listPrice,0);

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using `AUTO_INCREMENT` for the `order_id`?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put a `WHERE` clause and `LIMIT 1` into the query that sets `$listPrice`. You also forgot to set `@productId` anywhere.

You can do both of these in the same query.

```
SELECT product_id, list_price
FROM products
WHERE product_id = productId
LIMIT 1
INTO @productId, @listPrice;
```

I'm not sure why you need the `@product_id` variable, since it will be the same as `productId`.